# Can Joyride Jquery Button take us to another page?

Tags: javascript

```
<li data-button="Welcome! Let's Start">
<h2>Stop #1</h2>
<p>We will see this on first stop(Ask saheel what to be written   here).     Any valid HTML will work inside of Joyride.</p>
</li>
<li data-class="pane-update-and-events-panel-pane-1 .pane-title" data-button="Next: Upcoming Events" data-option="tipLocation:top;tipAnimation:pop">
<h2>Update Events</h2>
<p>We will see is some random things about Upcoming Events Here too.</p>
</li>
<li data-class="pane-upcoming-events-panel-pane-1 .pane-title" data-button="Move Forward" data-option="tipLocation:top">
<h2>Final Closing</h2>
<p>If it works fine, we have Achieved Level 3</p>
</li>
<li data-class="pane-article-panel-pane-1 .field-content" data-button="close" data-option="tipLocation:bottom;tipAnimation:fade">
<h2>Recent Article</h2>
**<p>We will see whether this page would take us there.<a href="******">Go to Desired Page</a></p>**
 </li>
```

I have written this code but what I want is, jquery Joyride should take the user to another page when the last pop up has appeared and user clicks on it's button where an automatically triggered action would run. So far I am unable to do that. Is it even possible?
PS: ****** would be replaced by the desired page address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about joyride but you could write some javascript to listen for when the last popup  has appeared and afterwards use

```
window.location.href = 'someurl.com';
```

Or some such to move the user to a new page.